# jQuery не обрабатывает созданный элемент.

Tags: jquery, html

Добрый день. Создаю Div с помощью jQuery:

```
$("#main").append("<div id='one'><a href="#">Тест</a></div>");
```

Однако если вызвать функцию

```
 $('#one a').click(function() { 
    alert('1');
 });
```

Алерт не срабатывает. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка?

Comment: Нагуглил вот что:

[code]
$('.svernut_btn a').live("click", function(){
     alert('1');
});
[/code]
Так работает. Правильно ли это решение? Есть ли иные методы?

Comment: live теперь deprecated. Надо использовать .on() в jquery 1.7 и .delegate() в более ранних.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Дело в том, что `.click()` навешывает обработчики только на существующие элементы DOM, чтобы навесить обработчик на тот элемент, которой возможно будет создан динамически, используйте **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** или ему подобные, делегирующие методы: `.bind(), .delegate(), .live().`

```
$("#one a").on("click", function(event){
    alert('1');
});
```

или

```
$(document).on("click", "#one a", function(event){
    alert('1');
});
```

Comment: А такой вариант сработает? $("#one a").on("click",  function(event){
    alert('1');
});

Answer (score 1):

Пример из вопроса не работает из-за синтаксической ошибки. Там неправильная
комбинация кавычек. Их нужно либо экранировать с помощью обратной косой черты
(`\"`), либо заменить на одинарные без ущерба для HTML.

```js
$("#main").append("<div id='one'><a href='#'>Тест</a></div>");
$('#one a').click(function() { 
    console.log('1');
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

В остальном код работоспособен. Вызов метода `.click(c)` абсолютно идентичен
вызову `.on("click", c)`, и замена ни на что не влияет.

Если поменять последовательность создания тега со ссылкой и навешивание
обработчика щелчка, код, естественно, работать не будет т.к. `$("#one a")`
вернёт пустую коллекцию, и метод будет не к чему применять. Если логика работы
требует вначале создавать обработчик, а затем ссылки, можно его навешивать на
корневой элемент и перехватывать всплывающие события от ссылок,
отфильтровыывая их. Для такой фильтрации надо вызывать метод
`.on("click", "#one a", c)`. Тогда каждое нажатие в пределах веб-страницы
будет обрабатываться, и если оно было по ссылке с родителем чей `id="one"`,
вызовется `c`.

Подробности про обработку событий — в [учебнике JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events), список методов
для обработки событий можно найти в [документации jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/Events).