# ajax получить id после отправки на сервер

Tags: php, ajax

Есть аякс запрос который добавляет записи в БД.

Как мне получить id только что добавленной записи в БД и записать этот id в response?

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: 'send.php',
    data: {name:name},  
    success: function(response){
        if(response == 0){
            $("#section").val("");
            $("#resp").append('<div id="resp">'+name+'</div>');
        } 
    }   
});
```

файл send.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$insert = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO section_list (section) VALUES ('$name')");

if($insert == true){
    echo 0; 
}else{
    echo 1; 
}
```

Comment: Верните результат выполнения функции mysqli_insert_id() после запроса.

Comment: записал после запроса $id = mysqli_insert_id($connection); в send.php, теперь как мне в response добавить это id?

Comment: Так вернете не 0 в качестве ответа через `echo`, а значение $id, а на стороне js проверьте: если отлично от нуля, то все ок и в `response` номер id добавленной строки.

Comment: что бы не создавать новую тему подскажите, есть еще скрит удаления записей, запись которая добавлена через append не вызывает скрипт удаления, что может быть?

Comment: События присваиваются при агрузке страницы. А при загрузке - это строки еще не существовало, поэтому и не работает. Вам нужно правильно присваивать события динамически созданным элементам. Таких вопросов тут много. Поищите. Напрмиер вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83459/jquery-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Comment: cyadvert, зашел на эту ссылку сделал как там велено, результат преждний

Comment: @LLIAKAJI значит что-то не так делали... наверное на этом этапе стоит оформить отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

JS

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: 'send.php',
    data: {name:name}, 
    dataType: 'json', // получает ответ в json
    success: function(response){
        if(response && response.success == true){
            $("#section").val(response.id); // ID новой записи
            $("#resp").append('<div id="resp">'+name+'</div>');
        } 
    },
    error: function(){
        // не забывайте обрабатывать ошибки
    }   
});
```

PHP

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST['name']); // SQL инъенкции это так не приятно
$insert = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO section_list (section) VALUES ('$name')"); // лучше юзать PDO
$id = mysqli_insert_id($connection); // ID новой строки или 0 в случае ошибки
$return = array('success' => false);
if($id){
    $return = array(
        'success' => true,
        'id' => $id
    );
}
die(json_encode($return)); // ответ в виде json
```