# Клик по конкретному элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть набор элементов с одинаковым классом. Код:

```
function click_popup() {
    $('.sossage').click(function () {
       console.log(this);
    })
}
```

Функция вызывается в другой функции, которая создает эти элементы, чтобы привязать событие на новосозданные сосиски.

Если добавлено три элемента по очереди, то при клике на первом возвращается один, при клике на втором - два, на третьем - все три элемента. Как это исправить?

Comment: А в зависимости от `this` вы свои действия построить не можете? Или у вас каждый раз в `this` новый объект?

Comment: @Visman в заисимости от него мне и нужно строить действия. Я только что понял проблему. При создании елемента, функция вызывается каждый раз при создании. Таким образом на предыдущие елементы вешаетяс еще по одному обработчику клика каждый раз. И выходит что если елемента три, то при клике на первый - клик срабаывает трижды. Как это решить?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83459/jquery-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82 посмотрите.

Comment: Приведите весь код добавления элемента

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5bwudL67/ пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно сделать быстрый костыль:

```
function click_popup() {
    $('.sossage').off('click'); // удаляем все события со всех элементов
    $('.sossage').on('click', function () {
       console.log(this);
    })
}
```

Но лучше конечно события вешать 1 раз, то есть ваша функция должна вызываться 1 раз и добавлять все элементы, а потом добавлять события. Вы же как то добавляете элемент на страницу? Так и вещайте сразу на него эвент.

Можно еще вне функции повесить один раз событие на все элементы через `document`:

```
$(function(){ // document.ready
    $(document).on('click', '.sossage', function(e){
        console.log($(this));
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно, на момент создания первой сосиски у вас есть одна (ей присвоили событие), второй - две( на первую событие еще одно и на вторую одно) и т.д. Можете присвоить после создания всех сосисок события по типу:

```
$('body').on('click', '.sossage', function(){
  console.log($(this));
  //другие действия на клике
})
```

Comment: Не может быть после. Пользователь может работать с n числом сосисок, а затем добавить еще одну.

Comment: событие вешается на все элементы которые есть и будут созданы после. Ищется клик на элементе  'body' и потом в нем ищутся все элементы сосисок)

Comment: то есть `on` работает по принципу `live`?

Comment: Да. В последних версиях jQuery live нету. Вместо него on

Answer (score 1):

При выполнении функции `click_popup` выбираются все элементы с классом `sossage` и навешивается на них обработчик события click. Ошибка тут в том что и на старые элементы навешивается данный обработчик повторно, можно решить очень просто. Не вызывать эту функцию при клике, а просто заменить на вот этот код и выполнить единожды.

```
$('.sossage').live('click', function () {
   console.log(this);
});
```

В новой версии jQuery нет метода `live`, по этому можно взять родительский элемент и сделать вот такой обработчик.

```
$('.parent_sossage').on('click', '.sossage', function () {
   console.log(this);
});
```