# Как выполнить функцию по клику на элемент, вставленный через append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок:

```
<div class="block">

</div>
```

При клике на этот блок в него вставляются другие блоки:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    $(".block").append("<div class='inner'></div>");
}

<div class="block">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Как выполнить функцию по клику на элемент с классом `.inner`?
Выполнение скрипта по клику срабатывает только если в коде сразу есть блоки с классом `.inner`, но если они вставляются через `.append`, то скрипт уже не выполняется.

```
$(".inner").click(function(){
    alert("Клик");
}
```

Comment: таких вопросов много. и ответов. Например вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83459/jquery-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Функция клика биндится не к фильтру внутри JQ, а непосредственно к объекту DOM. Необходимо создавать событие после добавления.

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
  $("<div/>").addClass("inner").appendTo($(".block")).click(/*тут функция*/);
}
```

или

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
  $("<div/>").addClass("inner").appendTo($(".block"));
$(".block>div.inner").click(/*тут функция*/);
```

Comment: У меня ваш вариант работает следующим образом: функция выполняется n-раз в цикле, но не по клику.

Comment: Вернее n-раз по клику на любой элемент с классом "inner". Как выполнить функцию только 1 раз?