# Нужно после выполнения ajax загрузить js файл (существующий), но чтобы первый больше не работал

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня есть js файл для обработки моего input (там код раскрывания списка и т.д.) и я ajax методом добавляются еще елементы input, но на них уже не работает этот js файл, а если я просто добавлю $.getScript("js/input_ajax_js.js"); , то скрипт выполняется 2 раза . Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

---

У меня есть обработчик всех элементов input (мой собственный input который можно отредактировать вручную и с выплывающим списком), вот как выглядит input:

```
  <div class="body_list"> 
     <input type="text" name="value_course">
     <div class="array">&#9660;</div> 
  </div> 
  <div id="list_rasp"></div>
```

а вот обработчик всех input:

```
$("div.body_list").each(function(){
    // тут я беру имя таблицы (из атрибута name) и по нему понимаю
    // какие данные заполнять в список (в <div id="list_rasp"></div> )
};
```

Ну вот мне и нужно чтобы после динамического добавления нового input у меня и он обрабатывался

---

```
//тело input (каждый input находится в теге div.bodu_list и рядом тег div#list_rasp в котором будет список)
<div class="body_list"> 
     <input type="text" name="value_course">
     <div class="array">&#9660;</div> 
</div> 
<div id="list_rasp"></div>   

$("div.body_list").each(function(){ //перебор всех элементов с input

  if($(this).next().html()==""){    //проверка списка на пустоту

    var teg = [];                                                                                                                        

    var name_table = ($(this).find("input").attr("name").substr(6));//убирает из name "value_"

    $.each(eval(name_table), function(i){ //перебор массива (имя массива взято из name в input)
        var val = eval(name_table)[i];
        teg[i] = "<div id='"+val+"' class='list_rasp'>"+val+"</div>" //создание списка          
    });

    $(this).next().html(teg); //заполняем div#list_rasp тегами в который данные из массива

    reset(); // функция очистки input при клике на него
    checking(); // функция выбора элемента списка при клике на него

  };        
});
```

Сам массив я беру из php методом ajax, выглядит так (напишу один):

```
var course = $.parseJSON(data.json_course);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/83459/186083

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не нужно загружать другой файл js для добавления событий к динамически добавленным элементам DOM модели.

Есть много способов в jqeury добавления обработчика события.

Первый пример который не будет добавлять события к динамически добавленным элементам:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
     $('simple element').click(function() {
        //Какое-то действие
    });
   ...
});
```

Наверное вы сделали так.

А вот пример добавления обработчика что будет работать со всеми элементами:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    $(document).on('click', 'simple element', function(e){
        //Какое-то действие
    });
   ...
});
```

Comment: Я понял к чему вы и я исправил, но у меня еще должна идти тогда динамическая обработка с помощью .each, не подскажете как?

Comment: $(document).on('each', 'simple element', function(e){
        //Какое-то действие
    });  
?????

Comment: @ArtyomDrebednyov Я не все понял что вы хотите сделать подробно опишите и задайте вопрос, желательно с примером куска кода и я помогу вам.

Comment: У меня есть обработчик всех элементов input (мой собственный input который можно отредактировать вручную и с выплывающим списком), вот как выглядит input:
    <div class="body_list">
    <input type="text" name="value_course">
    <div class="array">&#9660;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="list_rasp"></div>
а вот обработчик всех input:
$("div.body_list").each(function(){ тут я беру имя таблицы и по нему понимаю какие данные заполнять в список };

Comment: МДА, ничего не понятно из этого небось

Comment: @ArtyomDrebednyov Извините еще раз вы пишете в комментариях а тут не нормально видно код, задайте вопрос новый вопрос

Comment: я ответом на этот вопрос сейчас напишу

Comment: я ответом написал снизу

Comment: ещееееееееееееее добавил=)

Comment: сейчас посмотрю код