# Не срабатывают скрипты для блоков, которые были сгенерированы посредством .html()

Tags: html, jquery

```js
function generateNew() {
  var data = `<div class="step"> 
     <input id="opt21" type="checkbox"/>
      <label for="opt21">red</label>
      <input id="opt22" type="checkbox"/>
      <label for="opt22">green</label>
    </div>`;
  $('.new').html(data);
}

$('button').on('click', generateNew)

$('.step :checkbox').on('click', function() {
  alert('Чекбокс нажат')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step">
  <input id="opt21" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="opt21">red</label>
  <input id="opt22" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="opt22">green</label>
</div>
<button>Новые чекбоксы</button>
<div class="new"></div>
```

- Вот этот скрипт срабатывает на чекбоксы, которые были как html, но не срабатывает на сгенерированные вследствие нажатия button. Есть ли способ это обойти?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/nf9ko5jr/)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [jQuery не обрабатывает созданный элемент.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83459/jquery-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82)

Comment: @teran спасибо, там проблема похожая, но ответы на вопросы не помогли мою решить. Похоже, добавленные элементы через append и html() по клику в данном случае по-разному реагируют на событие.

Comment: проблема абсолютно та же самая, вы просто не уловили сути, что событие надо вешать на тот элемент который был и остается в документе, и в данном случае это `.new`: `$(".new").on('click', '.step :checkbox', ....)`

Comment: @teran все, разобралась. Вижу ваш ответ. Еще один вариант - надо было в функцию generateNew добавить алерт по нажатию.  https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/m6an5x9u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044474/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-html#comment1782467_1044474) рабочий, так что дубликат.

Из ответа по ссылке выше:

```js
function generateNew() {
  var data = `<div class="step"> 
     <input id="opt21" type="checkbox"/>
      <label for="opt21">red</label>
      <input id="opt22" type="checkbox"/>
      <label for="opt22">green</label>
    </div>`;
  $('.new').html(data);
}

$('button').on('click', generateNew)

$(document).on('click', '.step :checkbox', function() {
  alert('Чекбокс нажат')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step">
  <input id="opt21" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="opt21">red</label>
  <input id="opt22" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="opt22">green</label>
</div>
<button>Новые чекбоксы</button>
<div class="new"></div>
```

Comment: `live` удален из 1.9, `bind` и `delegate` устарели с 3.0, так что их упоминания в ответе несколько сомнительны